# Disc burner no longer detected in Ubuntu 16.04.04 kernel 4.4.0-130

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, burning, blu-ray

```
So back a while I experienced that my Blu-ray burner suddenly wasn't detected anymore. From kernel 4.4.0-98 and up it just wasn't there. So I just booted kernel 4.4.0-97 every time I needed to burn something.
```

Then finally with kernel 4.4.0-128 my burner was detected again. But it didn't last very long. Now with kernel 4.4.0-130 it isn't detected anymore again - and this time it doesn't help me booting kernel 4.4.0-128 or 4.4.0-97 anymore.

What gives? Can someone help me get my burner back?

Output of lshw that has to do with disc-drive:

```
 *-scsi:3
      physical id: 4
      logical name: scsi3
      capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: BD-RE  BH16NS55
         vendor: HL-DT-ST
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/cdrw
         logical name: /dev/dvd
         logical name: /dev/dvdrw
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: 1.02
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

I can read discs fine. But I can't burn Blu-rays. A few burner apps seems to let me burn CD's and even DVD's, but doesn't recognize Blu-ray media or won't let me burn Blu-rays.
I try ImgBurn via Wine which doesn't even find the drive anymore. Used to work very good. (I have to use ImgBurn via Wine for burning my own Blu-ray projects, because there is still no UDF2.5 filesystem for Linux burner apps here in 2018).

Yes, various tools seems to output the right data. But it just doesn't work anyway.

Output of cdrecord -v dev=3,0,0 myisofile.iso

```
wodim: No write mode specified.
wodim: Assuming -tao mode.
wodim: Future versions of wodim may have different drive dependent defaults.
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
scsidev: '3,0,0'
scsibus: 3 target: 0 lun: 0
WARNING: the deprecated pseudo SCSI syntax found as device specification.
Support for that may cease in the future versions of wodim. For now,
the device will be mapped to a block device file where possible.
Run "wodim --devices" for details.
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.36
Wodim version: 1.1.11
SCSI buffer size: 64512
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
Identification : 'BD-RE  BH16NS55 '
Revision       : '1.02'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Current: 0x0041 (BD-R sequential recording)
Profile: 0x0043 (BD-RE) 
Profile: 0x0042 (BD-R random recording) 
Profile: 0x0041 (BD-R sequential recording) (current)
Profile: 0x0040 (BD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x002B (DVD+R/DL) 
Profile: 0x001B (DVD+R) 
Profile: 0x001A (DVD+RW) 
Profile: 0x0016 (DVD-R/DL layer jump recording) 
Profile: 0x0015 (DVD-R/DL sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0014 (DVD-RW sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0013 (DVD-RW restricted overwrite) 
Profile: 0x0012 (DVD-RAM) 
Profile: 0x0011 (DVD-R sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x000A (CD-RW) 
Profile: 0x0009 (CD-R) 
Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x0002 (Removable disk) 
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
Drive buf size : 1900544 = 1856 KB
Beginning DMA speed test. Set CDR_NODMATEST environment variable if device
communication breaks or freezes immediately after that.
FIFO size      : 12582912 = 12288 KB
Track 01: data  7439 MB        
Total size:     8543 MB (846:27.44) = 3809058 sectors
Lout start:     8544 MB (846:29/33) = 3809058 sectors
Current Secsize: 2048
  ATIP start of lead in:  -150 (00:00/00)
Disk type:    unknown dye (reserved id code)
Manuf. index: -1
Manufacturer: unknown (not in table)
wodim: Cannot get next writable address for 'invisible' track.
wodim: This means that we are checking recorded media.
wodim: This media cannot be written in streaming mode anymore.
wodim: If you like to write to 'preformatted' RW media, try to blank the media first.
wodim: ERROR: Could not manage to find medium size, and more than 4.3 GB of data for a non dual layer disc.
wodim: Cannot write more than remaining DVD capacity.
```

Comment: Do you have the make / model number of the burner ?  What does `lshw` show?

Comment: Output of lshw added.
When the Asus burner didn't work anymore, I bought another one from LG. Doesn't seem like make and model means anything. The Asus burner went to my girlfriend's Windows machine where it's happily burning Blu-ray discs just fine.

Comment: Please edit question and describe "isn't detected anymore" - what exactly did you do, what did you expect to happen, what happened instead? Error messages, verbatim? From `lshw`, the `LG BH16NS55` (check if this is your model) shows up fine.

Comment: Can you compare the outputs of `lshw` from the kernel that works and the kernel that doesn't?

Comment: So the problem is not that the drive doesn't show up, the problem is that Wine doesn't work sufficiently well to allow ImgBurn to work? Incompatibility between Wine and the kernel can certainly be an issue. Can you try to make an UDF2.5 image in Wine, and use a Linux burning program? Try to use e.g. `cdrecord`, it should give sufficiently good error messages, **and please add error messages to the question**. We can't **guess** what is wrong.

Comment: What I notice immediately is that there is not a logical name for `/dev/bdrom` or other blue-ray disk logical names. Assuming your `lshw` output is from the non-working kernel, this may be a major clue as to what is going on.

Comment: As stated, it doesn't help me anymore to boot on an older kernel. That only worked for a while.
I can still use ImgBurn to create a UDF2.5 ISO. But trying to burn this with Wodim doesn't work. Will try with cdrecord too and add their outputs to the post.
So if `/dev/bdrom` is missing as a logical name, how can I add it?

Comment: @mr_lou are there any suspicious messages which look related when you run to the device or burning going wrong in `dmesg`?

Comment: I doesn't really matter if there's a `/dev/bdrom` symlink, or `/dev/cdrom` or whatever. That is handled by the `udev` rules, and makes no difference in functionality. `wodim` is and has always been behind the state of technology, I'd really try the original `cdrecord`, downloaded directly from Jörg's site. The wodim log shows clearly that the hardware is present, accessible, has BD profiles, and the correct profile is selected. So on the kernel side all seems to work fine, at least outside of Wine.